# getting error "could not open extension control file "

Tags: postgresql, sqlfiddle

I am trying to run this function but getting error

```
 CREATE EXTENSION plv8;

    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_func(data json) RETURNS json AS $$
      return JSON.stringify(data);
    $$ LANGUAGE PLV8;
```

here is my code

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/67b79/11

is there any way or any other online editor where I will run this code

Comment: I don't know of any "fiddle" like online service that has PLv8 installed. And none of them will allow you to _install_ any extension as that requires giving superuser access to everybody.

Comment: ok ...so it mean I will not check our custom function online .. ok

Answer (score 1):

Probably you have not installed a plv8 extension. Before execution the `CREATE EXTENSION` command, you should to install extension on server. This extension is not in standard package `postgresql-contrib` and then there is small chance so this extension is installed on server by default.

Comment: any way or other online editor where I can check my function of plv8

Comment: I am pretty sure, so there is not. This is not a common feature.